# file upload get null value in Codeigniter controller

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter-3

i am trying to upload image using ajax in Codeigniter without form Submit my html code is

```
<div class="profile-img">
                        <img class="" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/dist/img/<?php echo $adminData->image ?> " alt="User profile picture">
                        <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                            Change Photo
                            <input type="file" name="profile_img" id="profile_img"/>
                        </div>
                        <span id="uploaded_image"></span>
                    </div>
```

using this code i am send ajax on change event using given code

```
 $('#profile_img').change(function () {
            var file_data = $('#profile_img')[0].files;
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('profile_img',file_data);
            var admin_id= <?php echo (int)$adminData->admin_id ?>;
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/upload_image",
                method: "GET",
                data: {admin_id: admin_id, form_data: form_data},
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function ()
                {
                    $('#uploaded_image').html("<label class='text-success'>Uploading...</label>");
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $('#uploaded_image').html(data);

                }
            })
        });
```

it working fine but when we have hit controller its get null value both admin_id and form_data
my actual problem here i am still to trying get value but it always given null value 
my controller code is

```
function upload_image() {
         $data['admin_id'] = $this->input->post('admin_id');
        if (isset($_FILES['form_data']['name'])) {
            $config1['upload_path'] = 'assets/dist/img/';
            $config1['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $config1['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config1['file_name'] = $_FILES['form_data']['name'];
            $this->load->library('upload', $config1);
            $this->upload->initialize($config1);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('form_data')) {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            } else {
                $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                $data['image'] = $fileData['file_name'];
            }
        }
        $this->admin_mod->update_image($data);

    }
```

can anyone suggest me where am i wrong.

Comment: try with  `var form_data = new FormData(this);`

Comment: its give error like this Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.

Comment: have you use  `<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""  method="post" ></form>`

Comment: no i am trying to upload image without form submit

Comment: write  `<form>` Tag in your html code & try.

Comment: have you get data in `var file_data` ?

Comment: i am getting value here   $data['admin_id'] = $this->input->post('admin_id'); but it is given null output

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a FileList to `FormData.append` you have to pass a File. You can pass the first file in the list like in an array.

```
var file_data = $('#profile_img')[0].files[0];
```

Also your file is sent as `profile_img` you're trying to read it as `form_data`

```
    if (isset($_FILES['profile_img']['name'])) {
```